# Can't type in text field using redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a form in a modal using redux-form. I have several text fields, but you can not type in them. My suspicion is that the text field doesn't get the `onChange` event from the redux-form but I couldn't find any clue what am I doing good.

My code is:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Modal, Form, Message } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => {
  console.log(input)
  return (
  <Form.Field>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
    {touched && (error && <Message error>{error}</Message>)}
  </Form.Field>
)}

let AddNewModal = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting, closeNewSite, isAddNewOpen, submit } = props

  return (
    <Modal dimmer='blurring' open={isAddNewOpen} onClose={closeNewSite}>
      <Modal.Header>Add a new site</Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Content>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group widths='equal'>
            <Field name='domain' type='text' component={renderField} label='Domain' />
            <Field name='sitemap' type='text' component={renderField} label='Sitemap URL' />
          </Form.Group>
          /**
           * Other fields 
           * /
          <Button type='submit' disabled={pristine || submitting}>Save</Button>
        </Form>
      </Modal.Content>
      <Modal.Actions>
        <Button color='black' onClick={closeNewSite} content='Close' />
        <Button positive icon='save' labelPosition='right' onClick={submit} content='Save' disabled={pristine || submitting} />
      </Modal.Actions>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'newsite'
})(AddNewModal)
```

Answer (score 51):

I added the reducer and still got the same issue. At last, I found it must add the attr 'form'.

```
const reducers = {
  routing,
  form: formReducer
};
```

Comment: You have to call the variable formReducer  just "form", and then doing reducers = { routing, form } and nothign else.

Comment: so why you didn't upvote me. Eh? Why? #joking #pleaseUpvoteMe

Answer (score 18):

I found the problem. I forgot to inject the redux-form's reducer.

Comment: Aaaaaand... How do you added?

Comment: please provide solution

Answer (score 1):

I actually had a similar issue. I will post the code that I am working on for form validation with V6 of redux-form. It works right now but the things you want to look at are componentDidMount, handleInitialize, and handleFormSubmit.  Where I figured this out [link](https://codegists.com/snippet/javascript/redux-form-tutjs_parkerproject_javascript).

```
/**
* Created by marcusjwhelan on 10/22/16.
*/

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';  // V6 !!!!!!!!
import { createPost } from '../actions/index';

const renderInput = ({ input, label, type, meta: {touched, invalid, error }}) => (
  <div className={`form-group ${touched && invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <input className="form-control" {...input} type={type}/>
    <div className="text-help" style={{color: 'red'}}>
      { touched ? error : '' }
    </div>
  </div>
);

const renderTextarea = ({ input, label, type, meta: {touched, invalid, error }}) => (
  <div className={`form-group ${touched && invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <textarea className="form-control" {...input}/>
    <div className="text-help" style={{color: 'red'}}>
      { touched ? error : '' }
    </div>
  </div>
);

class PostsNew extends Component{
  componentDidMount(){
  this.handleInitialize();
}
handleInitialize(){
  const initData = {
    "title": '',
    "categories": '',
    "content": ''
  };
  this.props.initialize(initData);
}

handleFormSubmit(formProps){
  this.props.createPost(formProps)
}

render(){
  const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
      <h3>Create A New Post</h3>

      <Field
        label="Title"
        name="title"
        type="text"
        component={renderInput} />

      <Field
        label="Categories"
        name="categories"
        type="text"
        component={renderInput}
      />

      <Field
        label="Content"
        name="content"
        component={renderTextarea}
      />

      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
}

function validate(formProps){
  const errors = {};

  if(!formProps.title){
    errors.title = 'Enter a username';
  }
  if(!formProps.categories){
    errors.categories = 'Enter categories';
  }
  if(!formProps.content){
    errors.content = 'Enter content';
  }
  return errors;
}

const form = reduxForm({
  form: 'PostsNewForm', 
  validate
});

export default connect(null, { createPost })(form(PostsNew));
```

Comment: I tried to use mine like this. But it is not working either.

Comment: You don't seem to be including the connect function in your code. You can see at the bottom of my code. Also I am not sure what you are doing with `<Form.Field>`. In mine I have the <Field in the component, And render the <input> inside of a component call. Also you might want to make this a container and not a functional component.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect form reducer to your combine reducers

**form: formReducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

import authReducer from './authReducer';
import productsReducer from './productsReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    form: formReducer,
    products: productsReducer,
});
```