# Component crashes when re-render | React, Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await

I have a strange problem where my react, redux app crashes when I re-render the component. The component that I'm talking about it this one, `DoorsSettingsContainer`. Which has it's own path:

```
<AuthRoute
  exact
  path="/settings/:itemId"
  component={DoorsSettingsContainer}
/>
```

And when navigating to it the first time via a link:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/settings/${door._id}` }}>
  <p className="sub-title-text-container">Inställningar</p>
</Link>
```

It works fine, but when I'm on the `DoorsSettingsContainer` and refreshes my page everything crashes. Here's my component (I removed my imports to reduce the length).

```
// NOTE: There's no data here so my app crashes :-(
const getDoorById = (reduxStore, door) => {
  return reduxStore.fetchDoors.doors.find(item => item._id == door)
}

const getControllerById = (reduxStore, controllerId) => {
  return reduxStore.fetchDoors.controllers.find(
    item => item._id == controllerId
  )
}

class DoorSettingsContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchDoors()
  }

  render() {
    const door = this.props.doors || []
    const controller = this.props.controllers || []
    if (this.props.isLoading) return <CircularProgress />
    return (
      <div>
        <DoorSettingsForm
          onSubmit={this.props.updateSettings}
          door={door}
          id={this.props.match.params}
          controller={controller}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

DoorSettingsContainer.propTypes = {
  doors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  controllers: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  fetchDoors: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const door = getDoorById(state, ownProps.match.params.itemId)
  const doorId = ownProps.match.params.itemId
  const controller = getControllerById(state, door.controller)

  return {
    doors: door,
    controllers: controller,
    isLoading: state.settings.isLoading
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchDoors: () => dispatch(fetchDoors()),
    updateSettings: (id, door, controller) =>
      dispatch(updateSettings(id, door, controller))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  DoorSettingsContainer
)
```

And here's my error message:
[image]
I guess I should be mentioning that I am using async await for my action `fetchDoors`, so not regular promises. I've also read this post: [Why is componentDidMount not being called when I re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358991/why-is-componentdidmount-not-being-called-when-i-re-render) but with no luck.

Thanks for reading and hopefully we can sort this out together.

Comment: You need to investigate why `reduxStore.fetchDoors.doors` is `null`. Inserting a `console.log(reduxStore.fetchDoors);` might give a clue.

Comment: I tried your type and the only thing I got back was `isLoading: false` which I guess it's because of my `initialState` in my reducer for `fetchDoors`.

Answer (score 2):

You will first need to solve the crashing by doing a nullcheck on your Object
"reduxStore.fetchDoors.doors"

```
const getDoorById = (reduxStore, door) => {
 return (!!reduxStore && !!reduxStore.fetchDoors) ? reduxStore.fetchDoors.doors.find(item => item._id == door) : null
}
```

the next step is to find out why your object "reduxStore.fetchDoors" is empty. 
If i would be you, i would first go to your Reducer and troubleshoot if your store-state gets overwritten somewhere.