# React - why state doesn't set upon mounting, and doesn't change later

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-heisenberg-9cxb9?file=/src/components/card-detail/card-detail.jsx

When CardDetail component is mounted (when user clicks some Card in CardList), state property loadedData gets loaded with current datetime, but it doesn't display on mounting of CardDetail where it should: `<p>-{this.state.loadedData}-</p>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is componentDidMount not being called when I re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358991/why-is-componentdidmount-not-being-called-when-i-re-render)

Comment: Not really, I will shorten my question, because my post has 1 major question and one side-question. And the link provided (just partially) answers my side-question.

Comment: Now I edited it to specific question.

Comment: So just to be sure, the `-1608934180879-` below email and ID is not where you want it? Or is what's being displayed incorrect? You state it doesn't display where it should. So where DO you want it displayed?

Comment: it's not displayed on FIRST rendering. Say you click card 1, it doesn't display. When you click card 2, 3, 4... it displays.

Answer (score 1):

It does not update because you tell it not to.

`componentDidMount` happens **after** first render.
So calling `setState` will cause a re-render, but in your `componentShouldUpdate` you restrict re-renders only when the `m` property is changed.

You can either include the  `&& nextState === this.state` in your check, or you can use `componentWillMount` instead of `componentDidMount` which happens before first render.

---

So to be clear, the state **is** updated, but you do not allow it to re-render to show it.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Just a quick note though, `componentWillMount` is no longer recommended for use. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

Comment: Thanks. But I've read on several sites componentWillMount is a no-no... e.g: https://northcoders.com/company/blog/react-componentwillmount-to-be-deprecated

Comment: OK, I removed componentShouldUpdate completely, now it works. But I don't get it! It wasn't working in the first place - that's why I introduced componentShouldUpdate in a first place :(